# Can we create Hibernate project on Notepad?

Tags: hibernate

I am new to **Hibernate** programming, I am learning to write programs on **Eclipse** IDE.

Is there any way to create Hibernate programs on **NOTEPAD** ?

Comment: What do you mean by "notepad"?

Comment: we write the java program on notepad and execute using command prompt using javac and java command, so I wanted to know whther we can create Hibernate programs using command prompt.

Comment: The difference between writing a program in any programming IDE or a simple text editor is primarily convenience for us, the programmers. Yes, you can write, compile and execute a program containing Hibernate code with a simple text editor and comman prompt. I would, however, strongly advise against it.

Comment: You can try VS Code as well ;-)

Comment: Okay. Thank you.